# Send to Back Image in RDLC Report NAV

Tags: report, rdlc, navision, dynamics-nav

I am trying to place an image behind a table but it is not working. I want the image to take the whole body of the report. But instead the image is appearing first and below it the table. The image is not being displayed behind the table in RDLC report. How can solve that issue ? Z-Index ? I don't want to use background image because i am not being able to put conditional statements in the value field. I need to place an image in header,body and footer of the report

Any help. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible for many reasons:

- you can't have the same image in the header, body and footer
- you don't have pages in RDLC because the rendering is dynamic
- and so on

What I can suggest is to use some DotNet PDF library to print your report to a PDF and

- add the background image using the library
- or what is easier, merge the report pdf with and empty pdf which has the background image

sound compliacated but can be done in 10-20 lines of code

Cheers!